# Restore from backup?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical-questions

The cynic in me wants to post a question & answer

> **[I accidentally my hard drive](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally). What do I do now?**
>
> I accidentally
>
> - Wiped my boot drive
> - Tried to resize my partition
> - Tried to fix/adjust my Boot Camp partition from inside Windows
> - got a blank screen after a failed OS update
> - typed `sudo rm -rf /`
> - chown'd my entire machine
> - dropped my Mac/pad/phone & now it doesn't work
> - lent my Mac/phone/pad to someone & they...
> - disassembled my fusion drive
> - Used beta software/APFS etc on a mission-critical machine
> - Updated to High Sierra on an encrypted drive & the APFS conversion failed.
> - Stored my only copy of valuable data on a flash drive
> - etc etc etc

Then simply post the answer

> Restore your machine from your last backup

mark it as correct & link as a dupe every other question to which it applies.

So... my actual question is...
Would this get me a hat?
<sup>*Note: This entire question is not really meant to be taken seriously, but it's hat season, so why not.*</sup>

***Late Edit***
It really does appear as though this issue **ought** to be taken seriously - I'm adding real-world examples, as I find them. Let these become the...

### Darwin Awards for dead data

[Trouble with encrypted SD card](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286164/trouble-with-encrypted-sd-card)
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/how-to-recover-data-from-a-partition-overwritten-by-an-os-x-installer
[SD card shows up as Internal in Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287885/how-to-backup-a-mac-which-shows-as-unformatted) which was a follow-up to
[MacBook wont boot after creating two small partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286480/macbook-wont-boot-after-creating-two-small-partitions)
[Big file folder icon at the center of the screen when tried macOS high Sierra public beta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288392/big-file-folder-icon-at-the-center-of-the-screen-when-tried-macos-high-sierra-pu)
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296053/hfs-journaled-and-encrypted-flash-drive-does-not-accept-password
[MacBook Pro lost SSD during macOS High Sierra update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300327/macbook-pro-lost-ssd-during-mac-os-high-sierra-update)
[MacBook Pro OS corrupted while upgrading to High Sierra 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300974/macbook-pro-os-corrupted-while-upgrading-to-high-sierra-10-13)
[Accessing my contacts from broken iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301497/accessing-my-contacts-from-broken-iphone)
[Recover deleted encrypted boot drive, need all data back](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301893/recover-deleted-encrypted-boot-drive-need-all-data-back)
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302305/photos-and-notes-from-iphone-disappeared-unsolved
[Any way to undisable (not Unlock) my phone without factory resetting / restoring it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302681/any-way-to-undisable-not-unlock-my-phone-without-factory-resetting-restoring)
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305052/backup-to-shattred-screen-iphone-that-i-cant-unlcok-need-help-real-quick
[Unable to boot into macOS or Ubuntu after dd and partition reduction](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307171/unable-to-boot-into-macos-or-ubuntu-after-dd-and-partition-reduction)
[Data Recovery Tool to recover lost Chrome User Data Dirs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316532/data-recovery-tool-to-recover-lost-chrome-user-data-dirs)
[Folders in executable drive converted into 0 byte “Unix Executable” files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328008/folders-in-executable-drive-converted-into-0-byte-unix-executable-files)
[After deleting kali linux partition, macOS partition startup Volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359556/after-deleting-kali-linux-partition-macos-partition-startup-volume-type-fffffff)

Comment: I really like this. A lot. I'd be a rich man if I had $1 every time I asked someone: _"Where's your backup?"_

Comment: @Monomeeth And I would be a rich man if I had $1 every time someone replied with *"Wait...I was supposed to backup?"*

Answer (score 7):

Meta hat? Quite possibly. Would be diabolical to make you self Ask anD self answer on meta and on main for a pixel overlay.

I endorse the clear canonical question - especially if it helps get people a clear answer.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with creating a canonical question for this. With each one of those cases, whilst ‘restore from backup’ is a suitable answer, there are other answers which apply to specific cases. For example, adjusting Boot Camp partition from Windows has many answers beside restoring from a backup, but those answers wouldn't apply to the other cases. Canonical answers are great, but make sure they only canonicalise those questions which are identical.

Comment: Quick note about the votes: my answer was provided almost a week after the other, the voting may reflect this.